# Wrong number of items by the list creation

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples, nltk

I'm creating a list of documents that consists of tuples, each tuple consists of a list of tuples and a string, so it looks like this:

```
[([('NOUN', 'ADP'), ('ADP', 'NOUN'), ('NOUN', 'PROPN'), ('PROPN', 'ADJ'), ('ADJ', 'DET')], 'M'), 
('NOUN', 'ADP'), ('ADP', 'NOUN'), ('NOUN', 'PROPN'), ('PROPN', 'ADJ'), ('ADJ', 'DET')], 'F'), ...]
```

I'm using nltk to generate the list:

```
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
corpus = PlaintextCorpusReader('C:\CorpusData\Polit_Speeches_by_Gender_POS', '.*\.txt')
documents = [(list(ngrams(corpus.words(fileid), 2)), gender)
    for gender in [f[47] for f in corpus.fileids()]
    for fileid in corpus.fileids()]
```

The problem is, `len(corpus.fileids())` is 84 (what is correct), but `len(documents)` is 7056‬. So, somehow, I managed to square the number of documents. I'd like the list to have only 84 items.

I noticed that `documents[0]` and `documents[84]` are identical (so do `documents[1]` and `documents[85]` etc., of course). I could slice the full list of 7056 items, of course, but this does not explain anything... I'm new to Python and programming, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your program correctly you are trying to store the list for every document in a tuple, together with the 'gender' of the document, which is the element at index `47` of the fileid.

The list comprehension you use to construct `documents` first iterates over the inner list comprehension, and then over `corpus.fileids()`. When a Python list comprehension iterates over two iterables it will, for every value of the first, iterate over the entire second iterable. We can see this with an example:

```py
>>> print([(a, b) for a in [1, 2] for b in [1, 2]])
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

Instead, it seems in this case we can avoid the double iteration by instead  applying the `f[47]` to the fileid we draw from `corpus.fileids()`. This way every fileid will only be considered once.

```py
documents = [(list(ngrams(corpus.words(fileid), 2)), fileid[47]) for fileid in corpus.fileids()]
```

The entire program thus becomes

```py
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
corpus = PlaintextCorpusReader('C:\CorpusData\Polit_Speeches_by_Gender_POS', '.*\.txt')
documents = [(list(ngrams(corpus.words(fileid), 2)), fileid[47]) for fileid in corpus.fileids()]
```